# VIM: Highlight += with a background

Tags: vim, php, syntax-highlighting

I have been coding in PHP lately, which is weakly typed so integers are added with `+=` but strings are concatenated with `.=`. That means that I wind up using `+=` where I shouldn't and PHP actually then converts my strings to integers!

Is there any way to highlight `+=`, which I hardly ever use, with a background or something else very distinctive?

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167425/custom-syntax-highlighting-in-vim , http://superuser.com/questions/112632/custom-vim-highlighting-only-works-with-specific-file-types , http://superuser.com/questions/405354/different-background-color-for-multiple-filetypes-in-vim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

Create a php.vim in your after/syntax directory like this:

```
scriptencoding utf-8

setlocal nolist

syn match phpPlusEq '+='

hi link phpPlusEq       Error

" vim: ts=8 sw=2
```

Next time you edit a php file, the += should be highlighted as error.

Comment: Thank you. I have created the file `~/.vim/after/syntax/php.vim` and populated it with the content that you mention. However, `+=` is not highlighted in file `~/text.php`. This is on Kubuntu Linux 11.10, VIM 7.3. Any idea why? I do see that this is the right solution, though, so I am already marking it as accepted even though it is not working for me right now.

Comment: @dotancohen. Do :scriptnames in vim and you should see ~/.vim/after/syntax/php.vim towards the end of the list.

Comment: Thanks. It [looks like I have the text in the right place](http://pastebin.com/NjmQGmSj) but even so, [that file is not on the list](http://pastebin.com/KkiiP7Yp). Any reasons why that might be?

Comment: I don't really know but I'm suspecting kunbuntu. Can you do :set rtp? and check your run time path?

Comment: Thanks. `~/.vim/after/` is in the run time path, but `~/.vim/after/syntax` is not. Note that `~/.vim/after/plugin` is not on the list either, but my `~/.vim/after/plugin/matchparen.vim` file works as expected. Strange.

Comment: it looks ok. ~/.vim/after/syntax shouldn't be in rtp. i'm at a loss why it is happening. you can try: au BufEnter *.php so bla.vim and see if it works. if not, that means there is something wrong with your file.

Comment: Thanks. I placed `au BufEnter *.php so ~/.vim/after/syntax/php.vim` at the top of my `.vimrc` file, but `+=` is still not highlighted when I open either `test.php` nor `test` files.

Comment: No worry, lang2, I see that this is getting ridiculous. I'm googling and trying to see what I can come up with. If I do come up with something I'll mention it. Thank you very, very much!

Comment: That's OK. Before I leave this forever, one last thing to try: turn on filetype and filetype plugin. I.e. :filetype on, :filetype plugin on

Comment: Thanks. Still no good. I even moved my .vimrc file to see if that was interfering, but it did not help. No worries, thank you for trying so hard though!